# How to filter items from an array based on time using rxjs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, datetime, rxjs

I have an Observable that is emitting values that are arrays of objects. The emitted values look like this:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Foo',
        datetime: 'Thu Jun 29 2017 15:14:05 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Bar',
        datetime: 'Wed Jun 28 2017 12:10:42 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)'
    }
]
```

Please note that the `datetime` values are `Date()` objects.

What I want to do is create an "upcoming events" list that displays any events that are after the current time. To accomplish this I did the following:

```
events$.subscribe(data => {
    const upcomingEvents = data.filter(item => item.datetime > new Date());
})
```

The same can be accomplished by:

```
events$.map(data => {
    return data.filter(item => item.datetime > new Date());
})
.subscribe(data => {
    const upcomingEvents = data;
});
```

The problem with this approach is that while it does add any new items that pass the filter, it does not remove items when the current time passes the item time.

I know that this behavior is due to the fact that the filter only runs when the Observable emits a new value, but I cannot figure out a solution.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if i understand your question correctly, but why aren't you using the `filter` operator to filter the observable stream directly, instead of using `map` ?

Comment: Because the emitted vales are the arrays of objects, not the objects themselves. I want to emit the entire array, but I want to remove specific objects from it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a very elegant solution, but the only way I can think of to solve this problem is to merge two streams: the first being your observable, and then create a second stream of timestamps at some arbitrary interval to "garbage collect" your first string.  You'd need to add a `scan` to that merged stream so you can maintain an accumulator with the filtered date state at the end of your stream.  So something like this (warning, untested!):

```
// modeling your observable, not sure how you're creating it
const events$ = Rx.Observable.interval(3000)
  .concatMap(function (x) {
    return Rx.Observable
      .of([{title: "bar", datetime: new Date()}, {title: "foo", datetime: new Date()}])
  });

// Infinite timestamp stream
// this one checks every second, you may want to 
// check every minute, or every hour
const timestamps$ = Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
  .timestamp()
  .delay(0)
  .repeat(-1);

const merged$ = events$.merge(timestamps$);
const filtered$ = merged$
  // Starts with empty array until your first upcoming events array
  .startWith([])
  .scan((acc, val) => {
    if (val.timestamp) {
      acc = acc.filter(item => item.datetime.getTime() < val.timestamp);
      return acc
    } else {
      acc = val
      return acc
    }
  });
```

Somewhat kludgy, but I'm not able to think of a better solution at the moment that keeps all the state within rxjs.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do what you want by composing an observable something like this:

```js
const upcomingEvents$ = events$

  // Use switchMap so that each time events$ emits an array,
  // the observable that includes the upcoming events and the
  // to-be-merged updates of upcoming events is recomposed.

  .switchMap((events) => {

    function predicate(event) {
      return event.datetime.getTime() > Date.now();
    }

    // Filter the upcoming events and create a merged observable
    // that includes an observable of the initial upcoming events
    // and timer observables that will reapply the filter at the
    // appropriate times.

    const upcoming = events.filter(predicate);
    return Observable.merge(
      Observable.of(upcoming),
      ...upcoming.map(event => Observable
        .timer(event.datetime)
        .map(() => upcoming.filter(predicate))
      )
    );
  });
```